# 2.8 freestyle modifiers animation not works

Tags: animation, freestyle

Why does any animation not work for Freestyle Style Line modifiers?

Blender 2.80 and 2.81

Blender 2.79 works fine

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T72213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

[developer.blender.org/rB9f66062da73e954f7c00acd9d5d5ead9ac1e8863](https://developer.blender.org/rB9f66062da73e954f7c00acd9d5d5ead9ac1e8863)